# SSH to decrypt encrypted LVM during headless server boot?

Tags: ssh, boot, encryption, lvm, headless

When I installed Ubuntu 10.04 and, now, 10.10, I was offered the option of enabling "encrypted LVM" for my hard drive.
After choosing that option, I am prompted for my password during boot to decrypt the LVM.

Now, I am thinking about setting up a headless server that runs Linux (not necessarily Ubuntu), but I am worried that since the server is headless I won't be able to decrypt it during startup. Would I be able to SSH in during boot to enter my password for the encrypted LVM? If so how do I set it up? Or is there another solution? Again this question is NOT specific to Ubuntu.
Thanks.

Comment: Also see: `zless /usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.remote.gz`

Comment: I think @Nate 's answer should be the accepted one: it (essentially, since an edit is required to reflect changes in the linked blog) uses *public* keys throughout instead of *private* ones.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For newer versions of Ubuntu, for example, 14.04, I found a combination of [@dragly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29990) and [these blogposts'](https://stinkyparkia.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-with-static-ipst/) answers very helpful. To paraphrase:

1. (On server) Install Dropbear

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dropbear
   ```
2. (On server) Copy and assign permissions for root public/private key login

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.
   sudo chown user:user ~/id_rsa
   ```

   Remember to change *user* to your username on the server.
3. (On client) Fetch private key from server

   ```
   scp user@remote.server:~/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dropbear
   ```
4. (On client) Add an entry to ssh config

   ```
   Host parkia
       Hostname 192.168.11.111
       User root
       UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/know_hosts.initramfs
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dropbear
   ```

   Remember to change *parkia* to whatever you'd like to type `ssh my-box` to be.
5. (On server) Create [this file](https://gist.github.com/gusennan/712d6e81f5cf9489bd9f) at `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh`
6. (On server) Make that file executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh
   ```
7. Update the initramfs

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
8. Disable the dropbear service on boot so openssh is used after partition is decrypted

   ```
   sudo update-rc.d dropbear disable
   ```

You're done. Try it out. Check the blog post linked above for instructions about how to configure the server with a static IP address if that is something you'd need to do.

Comment: The linked blog has added a reference to appending a client's public key to the server's `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, even if it still goes through copying Dropbear's private key, which one can completely disregard. Following the rest of the instructions works for me, which means this should be the accepted answer (once it reflects that change), because it only uses public keys.

Comment: Wow... Did this work?

Comment: It worked in 2015, but I'm not using this setup anymore.

Comment: @nsg what are you using now?

Answer (score 24):

A guide to do such a setup with BusyBox and Dropbear is shown in [this blog post](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2011/09/13/remote-unlocking-luks-encrypted-lvm-using-dropbear-ssh-in-ubuntu/). early-ssh didn't work for me and is apparently not needed any more.

I have summarized what you need to do in the following. For more details, have a look at the post above:

1. Install BusyBox and Dropbear on your **server**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dropbear busybox
   ```
2. Update your initramfs on the **server**

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
3. Copy the private key generated by dropbear to your client machine. You may have to copy this to a new dir and change ownership to do this. On your **server** do the following:

   ```
   sudo cp /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.
   sudo chown user:user ~/id_rsa
   ```

   Remember to replace user with your username. Password logins don't seem to work.
4. Now you may transfer the private key with scp by calling the following on your **client**:

   ```
   scp user@remote.server:~/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dropbear
   ```
5. Set up your **client**'s `~/.ssh/config` file for easy login. Open it up with a text editor and add the following:

   ```
   Host myremoteserver
       HostName my.remote.server
       User root
       UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.initramfs
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_dropbear
   ```

   Change the Host to whatever you like and HostName to the name of your server. Let the user be root. It appears to be the only accepted user in Dropbear. Save and close the file.
6. Restart your **server** and wait for the passphrase prompt. Give Dropbear a few seconds to detect and set up its internet connection. Connect to your server with the following command on your **client**:

```bash
    ssh myremoteserver # or any name you chose
```

7. When logged in, issue the following command on your **server**. See the blog post for details:

   ```bash
   pid=`ps | grep "/scripts/local-top/cryptroot" | cut -d " " -f 3`
   kill -9 $pid
   sleep 35
   /scripts/local-top/cryptroot
   pid=`ps | grep "/bin/sh" | cut -d " " -f 3`
   kill -9 $pid;
   ```

   It will take some time (30 seconds) before you get to type your passphrase. Type it in when prompted.
8. Close the connection by typing

   ```bash
   exit
   ```
9. Your server should now have unlocked its encrypted hard drive and boot as normal.

(A huge thanks to the original author of the blog post!)

Comment: I don't quite understand the reason for moving around with private keys. It should be sufficient to copy the public key of you on the client machine to the server as authorized key for the root server, right?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible to create the key pair on the client machine and only move the public key from there to the server, but if I recall correctly I think there were some problems finding a format that BusyBox would accept. So reusing the keys that were already on the server was the only option I got working.

Comment: Any idea what I should do to get this working on Arch Linux?

Comment: @Gerhman Check out the [dropbear_initrd_encrypt](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dropbear_initrd_encrypt/) package in the AUR for early-ssh support on Archlinux.

Comment: @Gerhman archwiki page: [Remote unlocking of the root or other partition](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Remote_unlocking_of_the_root_.28or_other.29_partition) Haven't done it yet, but it looks interesting. Will have to check it out :)

Answer (score 18):

I think [early-ssh](http://dev.kakaopor.hu/early-ssh/) provides what you're searching for:

```
Early-ssh is a simple initramfs hook, which installs Dropbear SSH server into  
your initramfs, and starts it at boottime, so you will be able to do a lot of  
things remotely over SSH, before your root partition gets mounted, for example:

* unlocking LUKS encrypted crypto devices - 
  even your root can be an encrypted filesystem
* assembling/altering RAID arrays (mdadm)
* checking the root filesystem in read-write mode, 
  taking action in case of errors
* and so on...
```

There is already a .deb package available, so you're probably fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like this is exactly what I am looking for, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link to a good tutorial or howto?
I am stuck with early-ssh on my debian squeeze box.

Comment: Yes a tutorial would be great.

Comment: http://roosbertl.blogspot.de/2012/12/centos6-disk-encryption-with-remote.html

Answer (score 16):

Have a look at the cryptsetup readme for this in `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.remote.gz` (Ubuntu package `cryptsetup`). In there is a full guide to accomplish this. It is similar to [dragly's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29990/23363), but I think this is a bit more elegant. (Dropbear formatted keys, passing the passphrase via a FIFO rather than a fragile shell script, etc.)

> ### unlocking rootfs via ssh login in initramfs
>
> You can unlock your rootfs on bootup from remote, using ssh to log in
>   to the booting system while it's running with the initramfs mounted.
>
> ### Setup
>
> For remote unlocking to work, the following packages have to be
>   installed before building the initramfs: `dropbear` `busybox`
>
> The file `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` holds the configuration
>   options used when building the initramfs. It should contain `BUSYBOX=y`
>   (this is set as the default when the busybox package is installed) to
>   have busybox installed into the initramfs, and should not contain
>   `DROPBEAR=n`, which would disable installation of dropbear to initramfs.
>   If set to `DROPBEAR=y`, dropbear will be installed in any case; if
>   `DROPBEAR` isn't set at all, then dropbear will only be installed in
>   case of an existing cryptroot setup.
>
> The host keys used for the initramfs are `dropbear_dss_host_key` and
>   `dropbear_rsa_host_key`, both located
>   in `/etc/initramfs-tools/etc/dropbear/`. If they do not exist when the
>   initramfs is compiled, they will be created automatically. Following
>   are the commands to create them manually:
>
> ```
> dropbearkey -t dss -f /etc/initramfs-tools/etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key
> dropbearkey -t rsa -f /etc/initramfs-tools/etc/dropbear/dropbear_rsa_host_key
> ```
>
> As the initramfs will not be encrypted, publickey authentication is
>   assumed. The key(s) used for that will be taken from
>   `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. If this file doesn't
>   exist when the initramfs is compiled, it will be created and
>   `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` will be added to it. If the
>   latter file doesn't exist either, it will be generated automatically -
>   you will find the matching private key which you will later need to
>   log in to the initramfs under `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa`
>   (or `id_rsa.dropbear` in case you need it in dropbear format). Following
>   are the commands to do the respective steps manually:
>
> To create a key (in dropbear format):
>
> ```
> dropbearkey -t rsa -f /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.dropbear
> ```
>
> To convert the key from dropbear format to openssh format:
>
> ```
> /usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert dropbear openssh \
>     /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.dropbear \
>     /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa
> ```
>
> To extract the public key:
>
> ```
> dropbearkey -y -f /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.dropbear | \
>     grep "^ssh-rsa " > /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
> ```
>
> To add the public key to the authorized_keys file:
>
> ```
> cat /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```
>
> In case you want some interface to get configured using dhcp, setting
>   `DEVICE=` in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` should be sufficient. 
>   The initramfs should also honour the `ip=` kernel parameter. In case you
>   use grub, you probably might want to set it in `/boot/grub/menu.lst`,
>   either in the '`# kopt=`' line or appended to specific '`kernel`' line(s).
>   The `ip=` kernel parameter is documented in `Documentation/nfsroot.txt` in
>   the kernel source tree.
>
> ### Issues
>
> Don't forget to run `update-initramfs` when you changed the config to
>   make it effective!
>
> Collecting enough entropy for the ssh daemon sometimes seems to be an
>   issue. Startup of the ssh daemon might be delayed until enough entropy
>   has been retrieved. This is non-blocking for the startup process, so
>   when you are at the console you won't have to wait for the sshd to
>   complete its startup.
>
> ### Unlocking procedure
>
> To unlock from remote, you could do something like this:
>
> ```
> ssh -o "UserKnownHostsFile=~/.ssh/known_hosts.initramfs" \
>     -i "~/id_rsa.initramfs" root@initramfshost.example.com \
>     "echo -ne \"secret\" >/lib/cryptsetup/passfifo"
> ```
>
> This example assumes that you have an extra `known_hosts` file 
>   "`~/.ssh/known_hosts.initramfs`" which holds the cryptroot system's
>   host-key, that you have a file "`~/id_rsa.initramfs`" which holds the
>   authorized-key for the cryptroot system, that the cryptroot system's
>   name is "`initramfshost.example.com`", and that the cryptroot passphrase
>   is "`secret`"
>
> -- <`debian@x.ray.net`>, Wed, 30 Sep 2009

Thanks to [jap](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/24598/jap) for pointing this out to me on a different channel.

Comment: This seems like a much better idea (being described in the offical docs and everything) than hackish ps-grepping. As a side note on the unlocking procedure provided though, one might want to be cautious about typing the passphrase directly on the command line as it will most likely end up in a shell history file somewhere. A possible solution is creating a tiny wrapper script prompting for the passphrase using `read -s -p`.

Comment: note that there are issues with that approach in recent Ubuntu versions, i.e. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/+bug/595648

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be able to boot *unattended* as well as remotely, you should also look at [Mandos](http://www.recompile.se/mandos) (which I and others have written):

> Mandos is a system for allowing servers with encrypted root file systems to reboot unattended and/or remotely. See [the intro manual page](http://www.recompile.se/mandos/man/intro.8mandos) file for more information, including an FAQ list.

In short, the booting server gets the password over the network, in a secure fashion. See the README for details.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions, but note that 100% of your posts being almost-identical mentions of your product is [borderline behavior](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66148/what-is-too-much-self-promotion-and-where-do-we-draw-the-line), and you run a risk of being considered [spam](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87993/every-post-spam) (I'd have flagged your posts if Mandos wasn't free software or you didn't have a history of non-Mandos posts on other sites).

Comment: @Gilles: Done now.

Answer (score 4):

On debian 9 (stable), this solution was outdated. During the installation, I get a warning about `dropbear: WARNING: Invalid authorized_keys file, remote unlocking of cryptroot via SSH won't work!`, and I was not able to find the needed keys. This method is by the way really simple, and was explained to me on the great #debian channel (thank you again):

First make sure that `busybox`, `dropbear` and `dropbear-initramfs` are installed

```
sudo apt install busybox dropbear*
```

then add your public key (most of the time `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in the file `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys`.

Update then `initramfs` to take into account the changes:
: update-initramfs -u

That's all!

Note, if you want to avoid to have clash between the keys between `dropbear` and `openssh` (they share the same ip, but use a different key), you may want to put in your client `~/.ssh/config` something like that:

```
Host myserver_luks_unlock
     User root
     Hostname <myserver>
     # The next line is useful to avoid ssh conflict with IP
     HostKeyAlias <myserver>_luks_unlock
     Port 22
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then, you just connect using:

```
ssh myserver_luks_unlock
```

and once you get a prompt, type as suggested by the busybox prompt :

```
cryptroot-unlock
```

and type your password.

Enjoy!

Comment: Does this need to be `User root` ?  Ideally I'd want to disable remote login for root.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't remember (and I'm not using it right now so can't really test). I'd say no like that, but not sure. But anyway, it's not hard to try I guess, let us know if you try.

Answer (score 3):

On arch linux, there is an AUR package [dropbear_initrd_encrypt](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dropbear_initrd_encrypt/) that does what you want out of the box.  Works pretty well for wired interfaces.  I had to hack it up slightly for wireless.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, none of above answers worked for me. Moreover, copying a private key from server seems paradoxical.

Anyhow, [following instructions](https://gist.github.com/ceremcem/53fd10092b5e82ed1dba5d3011ac54c6) worked out:

## Boot your SERVER by connecting and unlocking the encrypted partition via your CLIENT

### Install mandatory packages (on SERVER)

```
apt-get install dropbear initramfs-tools busybox
```

### Append your desired public keys into the SERVER's authorized_keys file

Just copy and paste your public key(s) into `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys` on SERVER

#### Create the unlock script

Create following script in `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ="dropbear"

prereqs() {
  echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
  prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
  ;;
esac

. "${CONFDIR}/initramfs.conf"
. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

if [ "${DROPBEAR}" != "n" ] && [ -r "/etc/crypttab" ] ; then
cat > "${DESTDIR}/bin/unlock" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
if PATH=/lib/unlock:/bin:/sbin /scripts/local-top/cryptroot; then
kill \`ps | grep cryptroot | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print \$1}'\`
# following line kill the remote shell right after the passphrase has
# been entered.
kill -9 \`ps | grep "\-sh" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print \$1}'\`
exit 0
fi
exit 1
EOF

  chmod 755 "${DESTDIR}/bin/unlock"

  mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock"
cat > "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock/plymouth" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
[ "\$1" == "--ping" ] && exit 1
/bin/plymouth "\$@"
EOF

  chmod 755 "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock/plymouth"

  echo To unlock root-partition run "unlock" >> ${DESTDIR}/etc/motd

fi
```

#### Make it executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh
```

### Create a static IP (or skip this step to use DHCP)

Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` to add (or change) the line:

```
#format [host ip]::[gateway ip]:[netmask]:[hostname]:[device]:[autoconf]
#([hostname] can be omitted)
IP=192.168.1.254::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:off
```

### Update initialramfs

```
update-initramfs -u
```

### Disable the dropbear service on boot so openssh is used after partition is decrypted

```
sudo update-rc.d dropbear disable
```

### Testing

- Reboot your server
- Connect to your server via `ssh root@192.168.1.254 [-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa]`

Answer (score 2):

Headless server?  If it has a serial port, use it.

GRUB can be configured to work over the serial port.  Your kernel can also be configured use the serial port for outputting the initial boot messages, inputting the password to unlock your drives, and logging in.  (If your server supports serial BIOS, enable that as well.  Then you'll never have to connect a monitor to the machine at all).

Always a good idea to have a "non-network" way of getting in a headless server.

Comment: Great point! Though, "**non-network**" ways of getting in a headless server are mostly (*only*) relevant if the physical proximity between client/server is close; unless I'm overlooking some other possibility/feature of a Serial connection.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using the technique explained by others on this page (SSH in the initramfs with a kernel `IP` parameter to configure networking) for quite a few years now to remotely unlock headless Ubuntu Linux servers (12.02, 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04).

I even went so far as to develop a Python program ([unlock-remote-system](https://debuntu-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#unlock-remote-system)) that does the actual unlocking for me, because the process of doing this manually felt a bit fragile and I started to dread rebooting my servers, so in the spirit of "if it hurts it's worth automating" I encoded my knowledge in Python  (and this has indeed made it much easier to do regular reboots to apply security updates).

Since then I decided to also share my personal notes on [Remote root disk encryption](https://debuntu-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unlock-remote-system.html) with the world. The linked page contains quite a few details about the procedure (also some hints that are not mentioned here) and I intend to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Ansible role which does this for you. Just get the role [debops-contrib.dropbear_initramfs](https://github.com/debops-contrib/ansible-dropbear_initramfs) and run it. Refer to the [role’s documentation](https://debops-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ansible/roles/ansible-dropbear_initramfs/docs/) for details.