# How to open a port early in boot process to unlock LUKS via SSH

Tags: ssh, networking, luks

I have a fully encrypted server running Debian 7 and have set up dropbear and busybox to unlock the LUKS container via SSH (as described [in this tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/remotely-unlock-fully-encrypted-debian-squeeze) and in [this U&L answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29990/6761)).

Unfortunately, whenever I try and SSH to the server (over the LAN) at reboot, I get a "Connection refused" error. I have tried `telnet` and `nmap` to the default port (22) and both say the port is closed.

The server has a `ufw` rule to accept all traffic from the LAN:

```
Anywhere         ALLOW       192.168.1.0/24
```

I have tried changing the port that dropbear listens on in `/etc/defaults/dropbear` but `ssh` and `telnet` are still refused connections<sup>1</sup>.

How can I ensure that a port is open at that stage in the boot process so that I can connect to unlock the LUKS container?

Disabling the firewall makes no difference: `nmap` shows all ports still closed.

### Update 2/14

I added `break=premount` to the kernel line and had a poke around in the initramfs. `dropbear` has started, but the network is *not* up at that point. After exiting, the network comes up and boot continues until the prompt to unlock the LUKS device.

At this point, the network *is* up, and the host has been assigned the correct IP address, but port 22 is still closed.

The IP line in `/etc/initramfs-tools/intiramfs.conf` I am using is:

```
export IP=192.168.1.200::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:off
```

Consistent with the directions in `/usr/share/doc/cryptsetup/README.remote.gz` I have tried just adding the device option, but that is not sufficient to bring the network up and obtain a dhcp lease.

### Update 11/10/14

[Karl's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/160269/6761) was what was required: setting up `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot` was the key:

```
target=md1_crypt,source=UUID=8570d12k-ccha-4985-s09f-e43dhed9fa2a
```

[This guide](https://projectgus.com/2013/05/encrypted-rootfs-over-ssh-with-debian-wheezy/) also proved more up-to-date and relevant (and successful).

Comment: WOW! I completely did not know you could remotely unlock a fully locked LUKS.  Obviously I can not answer your question w/certainty but I would guess sshd has not started.  In my machine, sshd starts later in the process.

Comment: Do you have console access to the machine while it's in the busybox environment?  Can you verify that dropbear is actually running (via `ps`) and listening on the port you expect (via `netstat`)?

Comment: larsks - no, because at the console the prompt is waiting for the passphrase to be entered, and switching to another TTY just means a blank screen (if I understood you correctly).

Comment: Can you (temporarily) remove the LUKS encryption and verify that drop bear is actually running?

Comment: emory - I suspect that you are right; but I'm not prepared to remove the encryption to confirm that - I don't see how I can do that without risking the installation.

Comment: Could you start your machine fully and verify in which order are launched dropbear, sshd and LUKS. If your system is using the traditional init system, then it's a matter of looking in /etc/rcN.d where N is the default runlevel (usually 3 or 5). The scripts are run in the alphanumerical order.

Comment: Huygens - the order is: S01fancontrol
S01rsyslog
S01sudo
S02acpid
S02atd
S02cron
S02dropbear
S02exim4
S02mdadm
S02ntp
S02rsync
S02ssh
S03bootlogs
S16portmap
S17nfs-common
S18nfs-kernel-server
S19rc.local
S19rmnologin
S19stop-bootlogd

Comment: Have you tried using one of the `break=X` boot parameters to get an early `initramfs` shell? Whenever I debug filesystem encryption woes, I use `break=premount`. You can check what the situation is, resolve it, and continue booting.

Comment: Alexios - thanks: that's a great tip. I'll reboot when I next have access to the box and run some diagnostics.

Comment: @jasonwryan, I suggest you setup a testing VM and experiment in a VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this same problem a few weeks ago (Debian Wheezy 7.6) and after some days of troubleshooting I found out that there was a config file missing which was preventing to the cryptroot script on init-top to run correctly, hence it was not stopping to ask the password via ssh, killing the dropbear at the end of the sequence (init-bottom).

The config file is called `cryptroot` and should be under `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/`
If I am not mistaken that config file should have been created automatically during install (I have read just one tutorial talking about that config file) but somehow it did not (tested in a physical server and in a VM, same OS and versions)

It took me a couple of tries to configure it properly, since I could not find the proper syntax at that time. My cryptroot config file is as follows:

```
target=crypt-root,source=/dev/vg0/root,lvm=root
```

Once created the config file just update the initramfs and try again:

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Comment: You are a LEGEND! Thank you: I had struggled with this for ages and had pretty much given up hope of resolving it. My `cryptroot` syntax is different to yours, but your answer was enough to point me in the right direction. I'm indebted to you.

Comment: I'm glad you finally got it working. I saw your question while I was investigating my problem and I thought I should post how I resolved it once I got it running.

Answer (score 3):

The dropbear (ssh server) is supposed to be started very early during boot phase - earlier than the `init` (rcN.d) sequence and firewall init scripts; even earlier than / is mounted (it is encrypted too, right?). So it comes to `initramfs`, the pre-/ userland loaded for kernel by boot loader. The image is (re)generated by `update-initramfs -u` from contents of `/etc/initramfs-tools/`, including dropbear configuration in `/etc/initramfs-tools/etc/dropbear/`. To play with dropbear config, play with that one.

Thus, few points to check:

- dropbear doesn't start: it haven't been plugged into initramfs sequence well;
- default firewall denies all.

Comment: Thanks yarek: I think you are right - I have updated my question with a debian bug (and a fix that doesn't work). I have also tried disabling the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

The subject line is wrong. The problem isn't a closed port, it's a port which wasn't bound. SSHd hasn't started yet; that's the reason you can't connect to it.

Comment: @camh, are there any rules regarding that?

Comment: I was more focusing on the first sentence, which is editorial. The rest is rather terse to be a good answer, but I guess is still an answer. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @camh, I see...

Comment: I'm not using `sshd`: as the question states, I'm attempting to connect to a dropbear instance that runs on port 22 by default.

Comment: @jasonwryan, it doesn't play any role what exactly TCP service you're trying to use, what really matters is it's not started.

Comment: So, an answer would include information about starting it, would it not?

Comment: @jasonwryan, so you want me to fix your problem? :)

Comment: Well, I thought that was the point of the site :) I'll spend some time this weekend debugging in the initramfs and see what I turn up...