# Disallow change of init kernel parameter

Tags: kernel, security

is there any way to disallow changing init parameter on boot time?
I want to prevent situation when someone reboot my server, edit grub entry and get access without password.
Maybe some kernel parameters I can change while kernel compile?

Comment: [Full disk encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system)...

Comment: ok, but what if I want to reboot it remotely?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/how-to-open-a-port-early-in-boot-process-to-unlock-luks-via-ssh

Comment: A less secure but easier way is setting a password to GRUB.

Answer (score 2):

If someone has physical access to your computer, they can boot from a USB key, or take out the hard drive and plug it into another computer. To prevent someone from changing boot parameters, put the computer in a locked case or locked room.

If the computer is in a locked case but its keyboard is accessible to untrusted people, then you need a software means to prevent booting with alternate parameters. This is the job of the [bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting#Modern_boot_loaders), not the job of the kernel (the kernel isn't the software that's prompting you for parameters at boot time: it isn't even loaded into memory at that point). Be sure to forbid booting from any exposed external ports (e.g. USB, network) in the BIOS, and to set a password to access the BIOS configuration interface.

If your bootloader is Grub, activate its [lockdown features](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Security): add a `superusers` setting to your `grub.cfg`, as well as `password_pbkdf2` to set a password that allows accessing the command line. Be sure to add the `--unrestricted` option to your normal menu entry as well. See the manual for details and an example.