# Cannot run cryptsetup throught SSH?

Tags: ssh, luks

I'm trying to open a LUKS drive through SSH directly.

`ssh root@XX "cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 secure`

But, no password prompt and it stuck.

```
debug1: Sending command: cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb3 secure
debug2: channel 1: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 1: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 1: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 1
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 1
```

Is that something impossible?

Comment: Is that `/`? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37024/how-to-open-a-port-early-in-boot-process-to-unlock-luks-via-ssh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the prompt to work, you need to add `-t`.

```
ssh -t root@host cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/thing luksthing
```

(It also works if you just type out your password when it's "stuck" waiting for input, but it will echo in your local terminal.)

Alternatively, piping the passphrase works well enough:

```
echo -n 'password' | ssh root@host cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/thing luksthing
```

And to prevent it leaking to the process list and command history, better put it in a file.

```
ssh root@host cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/thing luksthing < passwordfile
```

At which point you might just as well use a truly random keyfile rather than just a simple passphrase.

Comment: Nice, I don't even need to disable echo in console now. FYI I just found out I can actually input password, only the prompt is missing ;-P