# Adding dropbear to initramfs with dracut on Fedora

Tags: initramfs

I'm trying to add dropbear to my initramfs so I can unlock the encrypted disk through a remote SSH session (as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot)). I'm running Fedora 16 which apparently uses dracut to generate the initramfs image. Can anyone explain (or provide a link) how to add dropbear to initramfs using this setup?

**Update:**

I've been trying to learn more about dracut, but I'm finding that there's not a ton of information out there. Here is my current understanding, if anyone can comment on this:

- I need to create a new dracut module which installs a pre-mount hook into the initramfs image.
- The pre-mount hook will start the dropbear server, before any attempt is made to unlock/mount the LUKS filesystem (which presumably occurs during the "mount" phase).
- With dropbear started, I should be able to SSH to the server and provide the passphrase to unlock it, as describe in the other post.
- I also need to add a pre-pivot hook that will stop the dropbear server before the boot process chroots to the final root partition.

Comment: If it's for the local network only, you could use telnet or netcat instead. I use netcat with a bit of random xor secret foo. Google finds several tutorials for dracut dropbear, did none of them work?

Comment: No, actually I'm getting very few (relevant) results on Google. I've tried "dropbear dracut" and "dropbear dracut tutorial". There's a few hits that are actually relevant, but none of them have been useful,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cobble together my own dracut module that adds dropbear to the initramfs and starts it during init. It also replaces the cryptroot-ask script from the dracut-crypt module (which asks you for your LUKS password) with a custom one which sits around and waits for you to unlock the filesystem yourself (e.g., over SSH) (as well as a little extra hocus).

I've put it up on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/bmearns/dracut-crypt-wait) if anyone wants to use or improve it. It currently doesn't shutdown the dropbear server after boot, so that's probably something that could be improved.

Comment: Any chance of a tutorial?

Comment: No, sorry. I did this a few years ago. It was my first and last time working with dracut or initramfs.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to find an alternate as I cannot get this or similar solutions to work (under virtualbox).   Plan B is to find a iDrac module for the server and use that.