# Send an email right before the password prompt of ecryptfs during bootup

Tags: linux, boot, email, grub2, startup

I'm setting up a home server which has full disk encryption enabled. In order to recover from a power failure the machine automatically reboots. I'm also able to unlock the disk remotely using ssh according to this topic: [SSH to decrypt encrypted LVM during headless server boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot)

The only thing missing is that I'm not informed when the machine reboots so that I know when to unlock the disk again.

Is there some kind of built-in functionality in GRUB2 that helps me achieve this or is my only option to set up an external site monitoring service?

Comment: To me, sending an email requires network access, a SMTP server, and possibly an API to manipulate it. Those things can only be accessed with a loaded operating system... which you don't have at GRUB (since it's actually the point of it). This may require another (functional) machine which monitors the first one.

Comment: When you say "full disk" do you mean every disk and not just the volume holding the production data?

Comment: As including a ssh-server into the startup process is possible, sending an email didn't seem to be completely out of the question.

Comment: That works because it builds Dropbear SSH into the initramfs. It really seems advisable to me that you just encrypt your data volume (and not the boot volume) and configure a `noauto` filesystem. At that point you can just ssh in and mount the encrypted filesystem in much the same way as you're wanting. You can even have a `mail` command inside `rc.local` to send off that email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of functionality is far too advanced for GRUB. GRUB can't even talk over the network except for TFTP.

The [SSH server that you saw](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot) runs under Linux. It is started early during the boot process, after the kernel has booted but before mounting the root filesystem. Linux runs programs from the [initramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) (or [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) on older systems) before mounting the root filesystem; that's how you get a password prompt on the console when the root filesystem is encrypted, for example.

Initramfs typically have a set of [BusyBox](http://www.busybox.net/) utilities. BusyBox can't send mail, but [suggests](http://www.busybox.net/tinyutils.html) the [ssmtp](http://packages.qa.debian.org/s/ssmtp.html) utility as a companion for this task. You'll need to build a statically compiled version.

An alternative approach could be to install the dropbear client and send the email (or other form of notification) from another machine. You can use the `command=` directive in an [`authorized_keys`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd&sektion=8#AUTHORIZED_KEYS%09FILE_FORMAT) file to restrict the use of a key to one specific command.

Yet another approach, if the machine is on a network segment which is protected from intrusion, could be to ping a dedicated port, or “port knock” some sequence, or send a ping with some constant payload.

Comment: Do you have an example for ssmtp usage with busybox or an updated solution? (The ssmtp link on busybox tiny utils page is down and the package is orphaned)