# Luks, ssh unlock, Strange behaviour, Invalid authorized_keys file

Tags: debian, ssh, initramfs, dropbear

I don't know why, but I can't manage to follow [these instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/ssh-to-decrypt-encrypted-lvm-during-headless-server-boot) on my debian stable. After installing dropbear and busybox, I tried to run `initramfs -u`. I got here a strange warning:

```
# update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-4-amd64
dropbear: WARNING: Invalid authorized_keys file, remote unlocking of cryptroot via SSH won't work!
```

Then, I tried to look in the file `/etc/initramfs-tools/root/.ssh/id_rsa`, but there is no folder `root` in the initramfs folder. I also tried to run

```
dropbearkey -t dss -f /etc/initramfs-tools/etc/dropbear/dropbear_dss_host_key
```

but there is no folder `/etc/initramfs-tools/etc/`, so this command also fails. Of course, I can create these folders, but I'm afraid that this strange behaviour does not come from a deeper error. If it can help, here is the content of the initramfs folder:

```
me@server:/etc/initramfs-tools# ls
conf.d  hooks  initramfs.conf  modules  scripts  update-initramfs.conf
```

Thank you!

Comment: This may not have been the issue here, but I was receiving the same error and it turns out that it was because I use an ed25519 key and dropbear just merged in support for this key type  a few months ago and it is not yet supported by the version in the Ubuntu 20.04 package at least. I had to create an RSA key to use in the initramfs.

Answer (score 8):

I finally found a solution thanks to some help on #debian. On recent debian, the procedure seems to be quite different. Here is the new one:

First make sure that `dropbear` and `dropbear-initramfs` are installed

```
sudo apt install busybox dropbear*
```

then add your public key (most of the time `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) in the file `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys` (edit: apparently on recent dropbear this file is now in `/etc/dropbear/initramfs/authorized_keys` according to Peter Schilling's answer below).

Update then `initramfs` to take into account the changes:
: update-initramfs -u

That's all!

Note, if you want to avoid to have clash between the keys between `dropbear` and `openssh` (they share the same ip, but use a different key), you may want to put in your client `~/.ssh/config` something like that:

```
Host myserver_luks_unlock
     User root
     Hostname <myserver>
     # The next line is useful to avoid ssh conflict with IP
     HostKeyAlias <myserver>_luks_unlock
     Port 22
     PreferredAuthentications publickey
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Then, you just connect using:

```
ssh myserver_luks_unlock
```

and once you get a prompt, type as suggested by the busybox text :

```
cryptroot-unlock
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Just some further details.

First, if your ssh client does not have a private/public key pair yet, you need to generate it with `ssh-keygen`, as shown [here](https://debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password).

Second, I would specify that you need to:

> add your **client's** public key (most of the time ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) in
>   the file /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys **on the server**

Here's how. On client:

```
c_user@client:~$ scp .ssh/id_rsa.pub s_user@server:id_rsa.pub
```

On server:

```
s_user@server:~$ sudo sh -c "cat id_rsa.pub >> /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys"
s_user@server:~$ rm id_rsa.pub
```

Finally, it's very important that you connect to the server as **root** (even if the root account is disabled).

Answer (score 1):

For those like me finding this question useful years later, an update:
[tobiasBora's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412152/550283) augmented with [solitone's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424658/550283) still works except that in newer versions of Dropbear the keyfile should be located as

```
/etc/dropbear/initramfs/authorized_keys
```

instead of

```
/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys
```