# LUKS secure automated decryption

Tags: security, luks, cryptography

I have critical data, let's say `machine learning code`, `GPG keys`,... etc.

I would like to create a workstation that will work somewhere else- in someone else's premises.

I don't have concern that someone may try to hack the running computer. Instead, I don't want someone to steal the disk drive and the data stored on that disk drive.

Tutorials like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996155/how-do-i-automatically-decrypt-an-encrypted-filesystem-on-the-next-reboot) one guided me to setup a password for protection, but let's say that the place happens to have frequent power outages -- I will not be bothered to provide the password each time the PC reboots.

One solution I found, but it is a quite hard to implement, is `LUKS` that takes the key from `TPM`, but I have `TPM2.0` which complicates things.

Would you please advice? Is it possible to decrypt `LUKS` (or a disk encrypted differently) non-interactively, during boot, keeping keys/password/code secure?

Comment: [Gentoo Wiki - Self-Decrypting Server](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs/Examples#Self-Decrypting_Server) [(Archlinux)](https://gist.github.com/frostschutz/ca44c333887490ab3dcf2a3cd83c78fe) but calling it secure is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: You may go with this approach: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5017/171196