# Remote unencryption start-up hdd ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ssh, boot, lvm, encryption, headless

So ideally I would have posted a comment to this thread [SSH to decrypt encrypted LVM during headless server boot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5017/417074), but apparently I am not allowed to do that until I have 50 reputation..

Anyway I have this machine where the HD is encrypted and I am asked to enter the password each time it boots.
I would like to be able to reboot it remotely which is not doable atm. I tried the steps in posts like this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188777/417074 but for some reason my system does not match the steps at all.

Right after doing step#1 and installing dropbear the directory /etc/initramfs-tools/root does not exist on my machine, why is that?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with dropbear so all I can tell you is that the paths changed; dropbear keeps its files under `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/` now. Googling for that path [found a different guide](https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/#remote-unlocking-overview) that might help you - or not.